# Calculating multiple exponential curve equations in dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I am trying to create a set exponential curve equations to explain price and units. In the illustrative data below, it would be one equation (or set of coefficients) for each geography-team combination. I need the coefficients so I can have an equation for each set: y = A*K^(Bx).

Illustrative data from csv (in reality, there are a few dozen geos and teams, each with 50 to 100 data points, hence wanting to avoid doing one at a time). Boston Celtics would have its own equation or coefficients, Boston Patriots its own, Chicago Bulls its own, etc.:

```
Geography  Team  Price  Tickets
Boston  Celtics  100  800
Boston  Celtics  95  810
Boston  Celtics  90  870
Boston  Celtics  80  1010
Boston  Patriots  117  500
Boston  Patriots  123  520
Boston  Patriots  110  550
Boston  Patriots  102  605
Boston  Patriots  97  630
Chicago  Bulls  82  200
Chicago  Bulls  80  205
Chicago  Bulls  70  206
Chicago  Bulls  68  215
Chicago  Bulls  62  228
Chicago  Bears  95  305
Chicago  Bears  91  311
Chicago  Bears  89  317
Chicago  Bears  81  320
Chicago  Bears  82  322
Chicago  Bears  70  340
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\PyCharm\Scripts\teams.csv')

data = data.groupby(['Geography','Team']).apply(scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t), data['Price'], data['Tickets'], p0=(5000, -0.3)))

data.to_csv(r'C:\PyCharm\Scripts\Coefs.csv')
```

When trying to run, I get the following error message:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
data = data.groupby(['Geography','Team']).apply(lambda x : curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t), x['Price'], x['Tickets'], p0=(5000, -0.3)))
```

Comment: This added array with coefficients. E.g. (array([  6.33e+06,  -6.4e-01]), array([[  9.17e+11,  -2.22e+04], [ -2.22e+04,   5.47e-04]])) Is there a way to have each coefficient value in its own column? 6.33e+06 would be in one column and -6.4e-01 in a separate column?

Comment: @skibbereen something like`data.groupby(['Geography','Team']).apply(lambda x : curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t), x['Price'], x['Tickets'], p0=(5000, -0.3))[0]).apply(pd.Series)`